# how to refer to the second Table of the same db

Tags: php, sql, database

I created a second Table within the same database, but this time, I get the Error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolea given in ... on line 30
I am new to php.
desired results: a new entry if the name doesn't exist yet, or update in the other case, if the new score is higher

```
<?php>
// score speichern
$zahl = $_POST["text2"];

// name speichern
$text = $_POST["text1"];
if($text == null){
    echo("Keinen Text empfangen.");
} 


// verbindung zu db herstellen
$db = @new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.de", "u465976419_k", "8o3SCoZLzh36", "u465976419_k");
if($db->connect_error){
    die("<pre>".$db->connect_error."</pre>");
}

$num = $sql->num_rows; // anzahl der Datensätze


#mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM Rangliste2 WHERE name = 'a'");

$neuezahl = FALSE;
$existiertkleiner = FALSE;
$existiert = FALSE;

// neuen sql eintrag 
if($zahl != null){
    //$namen = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name FROM Rangliste2");
    $nameexistiert = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT score FROM Rangliste2 WHERE name='$text'"));
    $dbscore= $nameexistiert['score'];                                       
    if($dbscore>0){
        if($zahl>$dbscore){
            mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM Rangliste2 WHERE name = '$text'");
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO Rangliste2 (name, score) VALUES ('$text', $zahl)");
        }
    }else{ //neuer eintrag eines neuen spielers
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO Rangliste2 (name, score) VALUES ('$text', $zahl)");
    }
}


//sql abfrage
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rangliste2y ORDER BY score DESC");
$num = $sql->num_rows; // anzahl der Datensätze
if($num > 0){
    while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
        echo ("$row->name:       $row->score\n");
    }
}
?>
```

the first .php script is the same. Only that 'Rangliste' instead of 'Rangliste2' which are the two tables...
How can one give me an error while the other works perfectly fine?
Please help, I appreciate every answer.

Comment: Hello. First of all you should really take a look at http://bobby-tables.com to learn something about SQL injection and prepared statements. The way you wrote your code, your database can be hacked in 5 seconds without really big know-how... just visit the page i linked and you'll understand what I mean. You should ALWAYS use prepared statements if your running querys with userinputs. NEVER, really NEVER(!!!!!!) put a user-input directly in your SQL querys like you did (the `$text` for example) ... Also after you conneted to DB you do a `$num = $sql->num_rows;` - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is error at the table name for the two variables $nameexistiert ..
`SELECT score FROM Rangliste2`
and $sql `SELECT * FROM Rangliste2y` y is extra here

Comment: damn your right! Thank's! Was another error and din't solve my first one tho